# Does ArcGIS 10 use parallel processing?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcswat

Does ArcGIS 10 use parallel processing?

In which version of ArcGIS can we get this facility, if it exists?

Is ArcSWAT single-threaded ?

Comment: v10.1 according to this post: [Arcpy Parallel Processing Environment](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/arcpy-parallel-processing-environment).

Comment: ArcGIS has used parallel processing in database connections since DirectConnect was introduced at 9.2, but that likely has nothing to do with what your question is really asking.  Please **edit the question** to specify the *exact* context in which you require parallelism, and what you would expect to gain from it (the vast majority of GIS algorithms are single-threaded, and wouldn't benefit from parallel operation).

Comment: ArcGIS Pro has new parallel processing options - https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/08/31/a-beginners-guide-to-parallel-processing-with-geoprocessing-analysis-tools/

Comment: There is likely a very different answer to the very different question, "Is ArcSWAT single-threaded."

Answer (score 1):

Yes (http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008971), 10.0 onwards.

For:

- Rendering basemap layers or accelerated raster layers
- Background geoprocessing
- Custom Python scripts

Comment: To some I might be splitting hairs, but more accurately, simply executing a tool in the background does not equate to parallel processing. Its executing the tool in another instance. One could argue that this instance is running in parallel to the app (ArcMap/ArcCatalog), but thats not generally what people think of as parallel processing when asking about ArcMap.